# Why is the project description missing from a Careers 2.0 PDF export?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, export

It's really great that Careers 2.0 now has a PDF export, but for my apps and open source projects, the description is not included. The part about what my contribution was, usually makes more sense if there's a rough description of the overall project included.

So:

- Can we get project descriptions included in the PDF export?
- Is there a specific reason why they were omitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original idea for the PDF generator was to create a single page resume algorithmically.  We worked through various prototypes for the projects section, including trying to just link to your profile on each open source site you have a project on (most people only have 1), but that did not provide enough information for a printable exhibit of **your** work.

In the end we ran some queries to find out how people were using the feature, and it turns out 70% of people had 4 or fewer projects listed, so we decided to treat them like work experience and let people cherry pick which ones show up and which ones don't for any given resume to be exported.

- Can we get project descriptions included in the PDF export? **Yes**.
- Is there a specific reason why they were omitted? **Vertical space and focusing on your work**.

Vertical space isn't so important since we relaxed the one page requirement, and I can clearly see how adding a description of the project could be beneficial.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: This will go out with the first build on Monday.